# How to get bitmap file name in Android if you have Bitmap ArrayList

Tags: android, bitmap, arraylist, drawable

I have an ArrayList of bitmap. I want to get the name of bitmap file of any bitmap let say

```
ArrayListName.get(5);
```

I have searched, but could not find any solution for my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to get the name of bitmap file of any bitmap

AFAIK it won't be possible to get the name of the Bitmap from Bitmap. You have to explicitly store the name of the file of the Bitmaps while adding them to ArrayList. Then you can get the name of the Bitmap on the basis of stored List of Bitmap names with similar index.